# How many presidents had decided not to attend the inauguration of their successor?

Tags: united-states, president, history, inauguration

Pres. Donald Trump announced that he will not be attending the inauguration of Joe Biden.

How many presidents have not attended the inauguration of their successor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### There have been 4 Presidents who had skipped their successors' inauguration.

This [Raleigh News & Observer article](https://www.newsobserver.com/news/politics-government/article247587590.html) listed those Presidents and their reasons for not attending their successors' inauguration.

- John Adams skipped the 1801 inauguration of Thomas Jefferson

  > It marked the first time in history the presidency was handed over to the opposing party, and Adams may have wanted to avoid stirring the pot between the Federalists and Democratic-Republicans, the association says.
- John Quincy Adams skipped the 1829 inauguration of Andrew Jackson

  > It’s unclear why John Quincy Adams, the country’s sixth president, didn’t attend the inauguration of his successor, Andrew Jackson.
  >
  > Adams [didn’t invite Jackson to the White House](https://www.whitehousehistory.org/press-room/press-backgrounders/white-house-transitions-fact-sheet) when he arrived in Washington, D.C., on Feb. 11, according to The White House Historical Association. Jackson also didn’t “call on” Adams.
- Andrew Johnson skipped the 1869 inauguration of Ulysses S. Grant

  > Grant and Johnson were nemeses, and Grant had previously said [he would not ride in a carriage](https://www.cnn.com/2020/11/11/opinions/presidents-history-skipping-inauguration-day-balcerski/index.html) to the Capitol with Johnson, according to CNN. Johnson was also reportedly [angry about his impeachment](https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/2020-election/biden-s-inauguration-will-look-unlike-any-other-s-only-n1249759), according to NBC News.
- Richard Nixon skipped the 1974 inauguration of Gerald Ford

  - Note that this is a non-scheduled extraordinary inauguration. Some [news](https://www.nytimes.com/live/2021/01/08/us/trump-biden#trump-will-not-go-to-bidens-inauguration) [sources](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-55419244) excluded this instance from their count.

  > Nixon, the only U.S. president to resign, informed then-Vice President Gerald Ford on Aug. 8 [he planned to resign and that Ford would take office](https://www.history.com/news/the-last-hours-of-the-nixon-presidency-40-years-ago) the next day.
  >
  > At 9:30 a.m. Aug. 9, Nixon and his family entered the East Room of the White House where Nixon delivered his final address as president
  >
  > [ ... ]
  >
  > He then left the White House and boarded the presidential helicopter.
  >
  > By the time Air Force One landed in California, Ford had been sworn in and Nixon was “an ordinary citizen,” History.com says.

Comment: Note: [BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-55419244) excluded Nixon's case.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Likely because it is a "non-scheduled extraordinary inauguration", as opposed to the others.

Comment: Also, every president who died in office, for obvious reasons.

Comment: It's trivia but the plane changed from being Air Force One to SAM 27000 in the air when Ford was sworn in.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the presidents mentioned in the answer by panda, none of the following Presidents attended the inauguration of the next President:

- William Henry Harrison (1841)
- Zachary Taylor (1850)
- Abraham Lincoln (1865)
- James A. Garfield (1881)
- William McKinley (1901)
- Warren G. Harding (1923)
- Franklin D. Roosevelt (1945)
- John F. Kennedy (1963)

Each died in office. They did not, of course, choose to "skip" the next inauguration.

Comment: This link will be useful for answer - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_presidents_of_the_United_States_who_died_in_office

Comment: I'd be rather disturbed if any of these Presidents _had_ attended.  I think we can all be glad they didn't.